# How to copy SID for storage with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sid

Say, if I get a user's SID with the following API:

```
TOKEN_USER* pTU = (TOKEN_USER*)pbytes;
DWORD dwSize;
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, pTU, dwSize, &dwSize);

pTU->User.Sid;  //Contains the SID I need
```

I need to store this SID for later use/comparison in the program. But how do I copy it?

If I do this:

```
SID globalSIDStorage;
globalSIDStorage = *pTU->User.Sid;
```

I get an error that:

> error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'PSID' (or there is no acceptable conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [CopySid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376404.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. The issue here is knowing the SID length. Is there an API for that? Also from my rough calculation, if I store SID as a binary array, it will max out at 68 bytes. Can it be larger than that?

Comment: OK, nevermind, it's `GetLengthSid`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446642(v=vs.85).aspx and the max SID size is in `SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE`